# How to pass Keyboard Input (int) in Java to String?

Tags: java, keyboard-events

I have a text file having names separated by tab. I need to print the name at the given input number. like i have

```
abc def ghi jkl mno
```

when the user enters 2, it should print "def". What i did is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NamesTab {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char ch;
                System.out.println("Enter the Number: ");
        ch=(char) br.read();
        System.out.println(ch);
        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Ass1.txt"));      
        String c=s.readLine();
        String[] tokens = c.split("\t");
        System.out.println(tokens[1]);
}}
```

but i could not pass the `"ch"` to `"tokens[ch]"`. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ch-'0'` for single-digit numbers.

```
System.out.println(tokens[ch-'0']);
```

Comment: How about if we need to enter two digit numbers ?

Comment: @gthmgeeky in case of multi-digit numbers your input portion will need to change in order to allow for entering strings rather than digits. Once you have a `String`, pass it to [`parseInt(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that ch always refers to a number between 0 to 9? If so, `ch - '0'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to provide a character in a space which should be an `Integer`. I understand that this "should" work in java, but just to be safe, cast `ch` to an `int` when you're getting the index of the String array containing the characters you want.

```
System.out.println(tokens[(int)ch]);
```